# Can not read property 0 of undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application when user has the possibility to toggle between the components.The idea of the application is next:

1. User click on `add field button` and there appears a input with placeholder `passenger name`
2. User fill something in that input
3. User click on `Add fields to inner` button and there appears a input where user writes a value
4. User click on `Submit inner` button and should appear `<Edit/>` component with the last value from input.
5. When User clicks on  on `back to default mode` button, the `<Edit/>` component disappears and appear default mode with input.

The component with problem:

```
const DynamicFieldSet = props => {
  const [fieldsOnEdit, setFieldsOnEdit] = useState([]);
  const [defaultMode, setDefaultMode] = useState(true);
  // const onFinish = values => {
  //   setFormVal(values);
  //   console.log(defaultMode);
  //   console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  //   setFieldsOnEdit(Array.from({ length: values.users.length }, (v, k) => k));
  // };

  const setFieldOnEdit = index => () => {
    setFieldsOnEdit(prevIndexes => [...prevIndexes, index]);
    setDefaultMode(false);
    console.log("defaultMode");
  };
  console.log("props", props);

  return (
    <Form.List name={[props.fieldKey, "inner"]}>
      {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {fields.map((field, index) =>
              !fieldsOnEdit.includes(index) && defaultMode === true ? (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Button
                      type="primary"
                      htmlType="submit"
                      onClick={setFieldOnEdit(index)}
                    >
                      Submit inner
                    </Button>
                  </Form.Item>
                </Space>
              ) : (
                <Edit
                  value={props.values}
                  mode={setDefaultMode}
                  keyForm={index}
                />
              )
            )}

            <Form.Item>
              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => {
                  add();
                }}
                block
              >
                <PlusOutlined /> Add field to inner
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Form.List>
  );
};
export default DynamicFieldSet;
```

Edit component:

```
export const Edit = ({ mode, value, keyForm }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("value inside edit", value);
  }, []);
  const back = () => {
    mode(true);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      edit mode
      <p>value: {value.names[keyForm].first}</p>
      <button onClick={back}>back to default mode</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Issues: When i click on `Submit inner` button i get the type error: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.
Question: Why i get this error and how to fix the code and to get the wanted behavior?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-ives-o81ue?file=/Edit.js:339-359

Comment: @Drew Reese, could you help?

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with `antd` but from some basic debugging I can see that `formVal` remains an empty object until the `Form`'s `onFinish` is called and updates state. `InnerForm` doesn't appear to receive updated `formVal` prop value when `SubForm` renders `Edit` and passes `values` through to it. In `Edit` `value` is an empty object so `value.names` is undefined and there is no property `0` on it to access.

Comment: @DrewReese, do you now a solution in RectJs, to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to always define a default value, or take care to have exactly that data structure:

```
export const Edit = ({ mode, value, keyForm }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("value inside edit", value);
  }, []);
  const back = () => {
    mode(true);
  };
  console.log("VALUE: ", value);
  // Default value definitions
  const { names = [] } = value || {};

  const { inner = {} } = names[0] || [];

  const { first = "" } = inner[keyForm]  || {};

  return (
    <div>
      edit mode
      <p>value: {first}</p>
      <button onClick={back}>back to default mode</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**EDIT**

For the toggle issue:

SubForm.js:

```
const DynamicFieldSet = props => {
  const [fieldsOnEdit, setFieldsOnEdit] = useState([]);


  const toggleSmall = i => {
    setFieldsOnEdit(prev => {
      if(prev.includes(i)) return prev.filter(ea => ea !== i);

      return [...prev, i];
    })
  }

  console.log("fieldsOnEdit", fieldsOnEdit);

  return (
    <Form.List name={[props.fieldKey, "inner"]}>
      {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {fields.map((field, index) =>
              !fieldsOnEdit.includes(index) ? (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Button
                      type="primary"
                      htmlType="submit"
                      key="submit"
                      onClick={()=> toggleSmall(index)}
                    >
                      Submit inner
                    </Button>
                  </Form.Item>
                </Space>
              ) : (
                <Edit
                  value={props.values}
                  mode={toggleSmall}
                  keyForm={index}
                />
              )
            )}

            <Form.Item>
              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => {
                  add();
                }}
                block
              >
                <PlusOutlined /> Add field to inner
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Form.List>
  );
};
export default DynamicFieldSet;
```

Edit.js:

```
export const Edit = ({ mode, value, keyForm }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("value inside edit", value);
  }, []);

  const { names = [] } = value || {};

  const { inner = {} } = names[0] || [];

  const { first = "" } = inner[keyForm]  || {};

  return (
    <div>
      edit mode
      <p>value: {first}</p>
      <button onClick={()=> mode(keyForm)}>back to default mode</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks, do you have a solution for the situation whan i will click on `back to default mode` to toggle just the component that i clicked not all components. The same issue is if i fill many inputs and after that i try to submit, in this case all forms will be toggled but i want to togle just that form that was  submited. Please, tell me if the issue is clear.

Comment: did you update the answer according to my last comment  or i did not understand? Because the answer is the same. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: the logic works, but when i submit the data, i don't see the value from input inside `<Edit/>` component. What could be the isuue? https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-ives-o81ue?file=/Edit.js:398-417

Comment: I guess thats a confusion with your data structure

Comment: solution based on this answer?

Comment: yes, your answer helped me a lot, thanks, i will accept the answer

Comment: could you take a look please here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809216/lose-the-state-when-toggling-between-components-in-react-js  , there the state is lost when i toggle components. Will be able to take a look?

Comment: Was this answer answered this question? `Can not read property 0 of undefined in reactjs`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217515/discussion-between-askmen-and-peter).

Comment: I will not aswer questions, where is not a good solution

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I think setting state interferes with formVal updating.

```
setTimeout(() => {
      setFieldsOnEdit(prevIndexes => [...prevIndexes, index]);
      setDefaultMode(false);
    }, 0);
```

Placing it in a setTimeout resolves it.

Comment: if i write `onClick={()=>setFieldOnEdit(index)}`, i can't toggle between  components and the `<Edit/>` component does not appear. Or i understand wrong your solution?

Comment: @Pavlos `setFieldOnEdit` is a curried function, allowing an `index` value to be saved in the enclosure and returning a function to be used *as* the callback.

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense then

Comment: @AskMen I figured out one work around; see edited answer

Comment: @PavlosKaralis, it works fine, but just for one field, if i submit first and after that i add second  i get the same error.

Comment: @PavlosKaralis, do you have any thoughts to solve the issue?