# Lose the state when toggling between components in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My application use toggle components.

1. User clicks on `Add field button`;
2. User clicks on `add field to inner` button;
3. User clicks on `add` button and upload an image, after a moment the image appears;
4. User clicks on `Toggle` button and appears another component instead of previous;
5. User clicks on `back to default mode` button and go back to previous state;

Upload component:

```js
const Demo = ({ field }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    fileList: []
  });

  const handleChangeHandler = info => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];
    fileList = fileList.slice(-1);
    console.log("filelist", fileList);

    fileList = fileList.map(file => {
      if (file.response) {
        file.url = file.response.url;
      }
      return file;
    });

    setState({ fileList });
  };

  const props = {
    action: "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76",
    onChange: handleChangeHandler,
    listType: "picture",
    defaultFileList: [state.fileList]
  };
  return (
    <Form.Item
      {...field}
      name={[field.name, "img1"]}
      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "img1"]}
      rules={[
        {
          required: false,
          message: "-"
        }
      ]}
    >
      <Upload {...props} fileList={state.fileList}>
        <Button>add</Button>
      </Upload>
    </Form.Item>
  );
};
export default Demo;
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-ives-o81ue?file=/Demo.js

Issue: (point 5), when user clicks to `back to default mode`, the image what appeared after uploading is gone, so the state is lost. 
**Question**: Why the issue appears and how to keep the state when i go back to default mode?

Comment: If the component is `unmounting`, in this case your `<Demo />`, the state will loose. You can do some `state lifting`. So you have to identify each `<Demo />` data from an upper state.

Comment: @Peter, could you help with this? Because i tried to take data from <Demo/> component but when i set state from there, there appears to many copies inside the state event i upload just one file.

Comment: @Peter, could you take a look on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811719/open-a-default-input-in-form-tag